# graphql - use queries in mutations - create a nested object

Tags: nested, graphql, mutation, graphql-js

I have a very simple model with `post` that embeds several `comments`

I wondered how I should do a mutation to add a new `comment` to the `post`

As I already have queries defined to get back a `post`with a given `id`, I wanted to try to have the following mutation syntax working

```
mutation {
  post(id: "57334cdcb6d7fb172d4680bb") {
    addComment(data: {
      text: "test comment"
    })
  }
}
```

but I can't seem to find a way to make it work. Even if I'm in a mutation, output type being a `post` addComment is seen as a field `post` should have.

Do you guys have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: How does your server-side mutation look like?

Comment: In fact, I think this article cn help a lot https://www.prisma.io/blog/experimental-graphql-106b07424435/

Answer (score 1):

You can't embed fields into other fields like that.

You would create a new input object for your post mutation

```
input CommentInput {
 text: String
}

type Mutation {
 post(id: ID!, addComment: CommentInput): Post
}
```

In your resolver you look for the addComment variable and call the addComment resolver with the arguments.

Your mutation would be

```
mutation {
  post(id: "57334cdcb6d7fb172d4680bb", 
    addComment: {
      text: "test comment"
    }) {
    id
    comment {
      text
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but you may want to just create a separate *updatePost* mutation that accepts the post id as an argument

```
type Post {
   comments: [ Comment ]
}

input PostInput {
   comments: [ CommentInput ]
}

type Mutation {
   updatePost( id: ID!, input: PostInput ): Post
}
```

The updatePost mutation here takes the id of the post and the updated post object as arguments and returns a type Post.
So I would use this like so:

```
mutation {
  updatePost( id: '1234', input: { comments: []) {
    id
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually this is not exactly what I want as what you propose would replace whatever is in comments by what you provide.
What I need is a way to use an existing other mutation within a mutation.

Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create `addComment` mutation that you pass post id to and then return a Post.

```
type Mutation {
   addComment( postId: ID!, input: CommentInput ): Post
}
```